# starting sshd on first connection to port 22 with upstart's new socket bridge

Tags: upstart, init

Recent Upstart has these new fancy systemd-like features of starting jobs on incoming connection via socket-bridge. I'd like to start my sshd upon first connection to port 22.

I now have:
`start on socket PROTO=inet PORT=22` in my ssh.conf and I have upstart-socket-bridge and upstart-udev-bridge jobs running.

The ssh job starts OK when I connect to my box on port 22 but sshd doesn't talk back to me. Its as if it doesn't receive it and cannot accept it. Retrying to connect will not help, even sshd is now running and should be accepting the connections normally. Upstart is still messing with it!

[Socket event man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man7/socket-event.7.html) say:

> When  an  incoming  connection  is  detected,   the   file   descriptor
>          representing the socket is passed to the job in question to allow it to
>          accept(2)  the  connection.  Additionally,  the  environment   variable
>          UPSTART_JOB  will  contain  the  name  of  the event ("socket") and the
>          environment variable UPSTART_FDS will contain the number  of  the  file
>          descriptor corresponding to the listening socket.

Does that mean that to take advantage of this, ssh needs specific support to passing socket FD? IF that is the case, it kinda spoils all the fun :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the socket bridge requires a patched daemon that can handle the socket that it is given.

From `man socket-event`:

> When an incoming connection is detected, the file descriptor representing the socket is passed to  the  job  in  question  to  allow  it  to accept(2)  the connection. Additionally, the environment variable UPSTART_JOB will contain the name of the event ("socket") and the environment variable UPSTART_FDS will contain the number of the file descriptor corresponding to the listening socket.

While normally sshd would simply create a socket and run listen() then accept() on it, sshd just needs to read the UPSTART_FDS environment variable and accept() on that.

Comment: OK, so just as I expected and wrote on the question (including the quote :P)

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend running sshd as a normal service instead of launching it on demand. sshd is quite capable of managing connections on its own in all but the most extreme cases.

If you absolutely must launch sshd on-demand, the following commands are helpful for troubleshooting:

- `ps auxw | grep ssh`, grep for ssh in the list of running processes.
- `netstat -tlp`, gives a list of the TCP ports that a service is
  currently listening on. SSH should be listed here, if not, sshd isn't
  configured properly.
- `ssh -vvv` (run from the client), detailed debug output from your ssh
  session, helps pinpoint the failure point.
- `nmap <hostname>` (run from a client--requires installation of the
  nmap package), list open ports on the host. If SSH isn't listed here
  but is listed in the `netstat` output, you've probably got a firewall
  issue.

Comment: `ps` shows sshd is running, `netstat` gives me only the upstart  socket `# netstat -tl
 Active Internet connections (only servers) 
 Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State        
 tcp        1      0 (null):22               (null):*                LISTEN` and `ssh -vvv` doesn't output anything useful as it cannot connect and `nmap` is irrelevant.

Comment: Unless your system configuration is very strange, that `netstat` output indicates sshd is listening on the standard SSH port. This can be verified using the -p argument to `netstat`, as suggested in my original answer.


If this is the case, the output of `nmap` is highly relevant, because a firewall issue is very likely.

Comment: Also, I notice you have (null) listed as the IP address in the netstat output. This would suggest that sshd isn't binding to an address correctly. Here's the output from one of my servers where sshd is running and accepting connections:

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Comment: That is the problem as originally stated: sshd isn't the one having the socket, but Upstart is. Upstart doesn't hand over the socket to sshd correctly. sshd is technically running, but Upstart holds the socket and sshd cannot get it.